# Python mapping dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have some dict containing months' short names and some data

```
data_in = {"Jan":2.0, "Feb":5.5}
```

and some dicts containing mappings

```
month_names = {"Jan":"January", "Feb":"February"}
day_month = {day:"Jan" for day in range(1,32)}
day_month.update({day:"Feb" for day in range(32,60)})
```

How do I obtain the following dict containing the original data with the long name and the day number as a tuple?

```
{("January", 1):2.0, ("January", 2):2.0 ...}
```

Comment: Note that `update` modifies the dict but returns `None`. So `day_month = {...}.update(...)` makes `day_month` equal to `None`.

Comment: your `update` is missing the end `)`

Comment: @depperm never mind the other invalid syntax, right? :)

Comment: day_month errors fixed.

Comment: is the "day number" the Julian day?

Comment: @downshift Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres my own try -

```
from itertools import count
c = count(1,1)
days = {"Feb" : 28, "Jan" : 31}

mapping = {(month_names[i], next(c)) : data_in[i]  for i in data_in.keys()  for _ in range(days[i])}

print (mapping)
```

**OR using your `day_month` dict**

```
mapping = {(month_names[day_month[i]], i) : data_in[day_month[i]] for i in day_month.keys()} 

print mapping
```

Output -

```
{('January', 1): 2.0,
 ('January', 2): 2.0,
 ('January', 3): 2.0,
 ('January', 4): 2.0,
 ('January', 5): 2.0,
 ('January', 6): 2.0,
 ('January', 7): 2.0,
 ('January', 8): 2.0,
 ('January', 9): 2.0,
 ('January', 10): 2.0,
 ('January', 11): 2.0,
 ('January', 12): 2.0,
 ('January', 13): 2.0,
 ('January', 14): 2.0,
 ('January', 15): 2.0,
 ('January', 16): 2.0,
 ('January', 17): 2.0,
 ('January', 18): 2.0,
 ('January', 19): 2.0,
 ('January', 20): 2.0,
 ('January', 21): 2.0,
 ('January', 22): 2.0,
 ('January', 23): 2.0,
 ('January', 24): 2.0,
  ..... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you want to do is iterate over the keys of the `day_month` dictionary, and for each take the matching entry for the value from `month_names` and `data_in`, so it should look something like:

```
result = {}
for day in day_month.keys():
    short_month = day_month[day]
    data = data_in[short_month]
    name = month_names[short_month]
    new_key = (name, day)
    result[new_key] = data
```

Comment: @depperm - care to elaborate?

Comment: put this after his code and it gives error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Comment: @depperm - yeah, I saw the comment on the post itself, and got that point. But it has nothing to do with the answer. I agree that using the right syntax is better, but this is not what the question is about.